# Run exe file with parameter from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]I have created a console application and now I want to execute this `.exe` file from SQL Server. Running this query only gets `null` output. Please help me.

```
    DECLARE @CMDSQL VARCHAR(1000), 
            @Reportname VARCHAR(100),
            @TerminalCode VARCHAR(10),
            @FinYear VARCHAR(10)  

    SET @Reportname =('05 - Import Load Delivery')  
    SET @FinYear='2017-18'  
    SET @TerminalCode='BOM'  
    SET @CMDSQL = '"D:\ExportToExcel.exe" ' + @Reportname + ' ' + @TerminalCode + ' ' + @FinYear  

    --print @CMDSQL  
    Exec master..xp_cmdshell @CMDSQL
```

Comment: Try enclosing the parameter values in quotes: `SET @CMDSQL='"D:\ExportToExcel.exe" "'+@Reportname+'" "'+@TerminalCode+'" "'+@FinYear + '"'`

Comment: thatx Dan Guzman but this is also not working

Comment: `NULL` is expected if your app doesn't produce console output. Does it write messages to the console, success or failure?

Comment: Yes its write the success message also this exe file wrok perfectly through sql server when i hardcode the input parameters.

Comment: Start with debugging work. Have your app write all the incoming parameters to a file on disk, and check to see if you are getting the information you are looking for.  Odds are that each space in your `@Reportname` parameter becomes a separate parameter.

Comment: thanks laughing Vergil, i have  written code to write incommin parameter but its given null value may be because of the parameters are not passed properly

Comment: What does `EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'DIR D:\*.exe'` return?

Comment: Hi Nich, if .exe file successfully run then its create new excel file on perticular location and given step by step information like enter in try block and accpet 1 arg then pass agr. if failed the enter in catch, Exceptio message shows, then passed parameter etc. but when i i execute the .exe with parameter from sql then then all parameters return null value and exception message 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: i have attachted the screen short of the error the null value is passed parameter

Comment: I don't know if you already solved that issue, but try to change the xp_cmdshell.
 This link can help you: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2014/replace-xpcmdshell-command-line-use-with-sql-server-agent/    
If it works, please, let me know.

Comment: Please ensure you've followed the recommended best practices for securing xp_cmdshell , it's particularly vulnerable to misuse [Microsoft Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SET @CMDSQL = 'CMD /S /C " "D:\ExportToExcel.exe"  "' + @ReportName + '" "' + @TerminalCode + '" "' + @FinYear + '" "'
```

*It is important to quote the individual parameters as @DanGuzman suggested.*

Answer (score 0):

No answer on this post. I found that including your ENTIRE statement within double quotes works. So you end up with nested double quotes.

So in your example:

```
SET @CMDSQL = 'CMD /S /C " ""D:\ExportToExcel.exe"  "' + @ReportName + '" "' + @TerminalCode + '" "' + @FinYear + '" ""'
```

or in mine that I was trying to figure out:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell '""C:\XML\ExecURL.exe" "http://devserver/app/retreiveshippinglabels/RGAGetLabels?RMA_NO=171269""';
```